# MySQL: User-Define Function

Tags: mysql, database, user-defined-functions

For the user-define function in MYSQL,

I passs in one parameter to udf (a int);

if a is NULL return 2.0;
else return 3.0

```
`DELIMITER !
CREATE FUNCTION return val(a INTEGER) RETURNS NUMERIC(10,2)
BEGIN
  If (isNULL(a)) THEN return 2.0
  ELSE RETURN 3.0;
  END IF;
END!

DELIMITER ;`
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Yes, apparently, there isn't a function call `isNull`, so how can I tell about whether the `a` is a NULL

Comment: So do I change it to `if (SELECT a IS NULL) THEN RETURN 2.0`

Comment: how about replacing isNull by ifNull ?

Comment: @RyanVincent, thanks for your input

Comment: @bogzy, you mean `IF ( IFNULL(a, 0)) THEN ....` ?

Comment: @wrek, yup. But you still have to make a conditional statement after that since you will having a static value of those non null values.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try this one using CASE statement:

```
CASE WHEN a IS NULL or a = ''
     then '2.0'
     else '3.0'
END
```